# Qt5 QtCreator ugly fonts in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu, fonts

My fonts in general within QtCreator inside Ubuntu 13.04 looks 'ugly' when compared to how they looked in 12.10.

12.10 still used Qt4, so did something regarding the font rendering in Qt5 and the most up to date QtCreator change then?

If so, is there a workaround and or fix for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are reported bugs for fonst in these links: [link1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtbase-opensource-src/+bug/1126210), [link2](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-27106)

In the first one, the package

```
qtbase-opensource-src - 5.0.1+dfsg-0ubuntu4
```

solves the problem. Is your problem similar to them?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem under elementary OS which is based on Ubuntu. I found a solution in the [ArchLinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172361) that solved it, at least for me.

Short answer: Create a file named `/etc/fonts/local.conf` with the following content:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>

 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match> 

 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
   <const>hintslight</const>
  </edit>
 </match>

 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>

 <match target="font">
   <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
     <const>rgb</const>
   </edit>
 </match>

 <match target="font">
   <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
     <const>lcddefault</const>
   </edit>
 </match>

</fontconfig>
```

Comment: works for me: fonts now almost identical to gtk and qt4
OS: xubuntu-17.04

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for version 14.04, and it seems to work on ubuntu 13.04 version too:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/285862/qt5-font-rendering-in-ubuntu-13-04/569313#569313

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Qt5 Configuration Tool](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Qt5+Configuration+Tool?content=168066) to tell Qt 5 to use GTK+ style and change font settings